# The 5000th Question

Tags: wordplay, rebus

This is a good one, a rebus as I like it. Plus, this is the Question #5000.

```
  1. Mon
  2. Tue
  3. Wed
  4. Thu
  5. Fri
  6. Sat
  7. Sun
```

Happy Solving. :)

Comment: Is this somehow related to it being the 5000th question?

Comment: According to my Site Stats this is the 4999th question, and I think it;s actually the 29068th question (the number in the url) but there are 4999 still left or something like that.

Comment: It's the Beatles song "Eight Days a Week" with the eighth day left out to make it a little more challenging. Nice.

Comment: @IvoBeckers The 29068 also includes answers.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

My guess is

> Your days are numbered

Answer (score 4):

> Counting down the days.

As, one can notice...

> Each day of the week is written with numeric bullets and the word `day` is omitted from each one of them.

Also,

> This might be a slight hint towards the upcoming movie, [Batman v Superman](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2975590/), almost a week to go!

Comment: You are close, stay on track.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is

> Endless days, the days are endless or some variation of that since it is a list of the beginnings of the days only. I note that there is no period at the end of the letters as would be usual for abbreviations.

Answer (score 2):

> September 5000 or December 5000

Because:

> According to [Calendar Donkey](http://5000.calendardonkey.com/), these are the listings for these months.

Comment: The number 5000 is not of importance, I guess I should have played with it though. Sorry to break your heart.

Answer (score 2):

How about

> Counting the days 'til the weekend.